# How to change a particular input field value of a GridView while updating that row in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one form where a user has two date input fields(from_date,to_date).

Based on the dates, the number of days is calculated and stored in third input(days).

This form of data is stored in SQL database.

This table is displayed as a grid view on the next page where the user can edit the rows data. But while updating the rows, all the input fields get updated successfully, but the problem is that the number_of_days input field needs to get updated on its own based on the two dates entered.

But I have no idea where I need to code the logic in order to update that third input in the grid view.

Grid view design:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-bordered table-sm" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Sr_No" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr_No" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Sr_No">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Sr_No") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sr_No") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From_Date" SortExpression="From_Date">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# Bind("From_Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("From_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To_Date" SortExpression="To_Date">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# Bind("To_Date") %>' OnChange="abc()"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("To_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No_Of_Days" SortExpression="No_Of_Days">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("No_Of_Days") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("No_Of_Days") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



                <asp:TemplateField>  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind update:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
    Label Sr_No = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    TextBox From = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
    TextBox To = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox;
    TextBox No = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox;
    con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tablename set Sr_No='" + From_Date='" + From.Text + "',To_Date='" + To.Text + "',No='" + No.Text + "' where Sr_No=" + Convert.ToInt32(Sr_No.Text), con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    ShowData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your No_Of_Days TemplateField as below

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No_Of_Days" SortExpression="No_Of_Days">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# (Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("To_Date"))!=null && Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("From_Date"))!=null)?(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("To_Date"))-Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("From_Date"))).Days:0 %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#  (Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("To_Date"))!=null && Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("From_Date"))!=null)?(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("To_Date"))-Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("From_Date"))).Days:0 %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. It shows error : Null values arent't accepted. It is as if textbox remains empty and nothing happens when using this code